# how to get yahoo search result according to page number in YQL/pipes?

Tags: yql, yahoo-pipes

we can get only the first 10 urls result using

> select url from search.web where
>   query="stackoverflow"

how can i get results accorridng to page numbers like result from 60 to 70, or 90 to 100 and son on..??

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is:

```
SELECT url FROM search.web(0,60) WHERE query="stackoverflow"
```

Replace 60 with whatever other number your desire. Max is 500 afaik for the search.web YQL table because that is the limit of Yahoo BOSS which is used in this table.

You can also replace the 0 with e.g. 10, to skip the first 10 results. So using `search.web(10,60)` would still give you 60 results while skipping the first 10.

Also see the YQL documentation on [remote limits](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/paging.html#remote_limits) - thats how this search.web(0,60) syntax is called.